# Using cordova-plugin-playlist without knowledge of TypeScript

Tags: typescript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have been using Cordova to build apps for a few years now, but I've somehow never encountered TypeScript until now. I'm currently in a situation where I need to use cordova-plugin-playlist, but there is no documentation and the example file is an Angular5/Ionic implementation written in TypeScript.

Is it possible to implement this plugin without using TypeScript, using pure JS, as I normally do? For example, the cordova-plugin-media plugin exposes an object type called Media, which I can instantiate within my project JS files. Can I interface with cordova-plugin-playlist in a similar way?

I apologize for the possibly broad question. I am just unsure of how to begin to attack this. Thank you for listening!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Yes, that is indeed possible. You can use the `declare` keyword or use `.d.ts` (declaration) files that tell the IDE about specific classes, variables etc and how they look like, without them being JS files.

This is only currently possible when using pure JavaScript if there's a `tsconfig.json` file in the project root, and you're using Visual Studio Code, which includes Project Salsa.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html

Comment: Thank you! You mention compilation. I should mention that I'm not using any kind of compiler (aside from building the app with Cordova). Does Cordova automatically do the compilation that you're talking about? My workflow is basically create HTML, CSS, and JS files and then build the Cordova app, and Cordova packages my HTML, CSS, and JS files directly within the app to be displayed on the built in web browser. I see it as making a website with an app wrapper. Do I need extra tools in order to compile the TypeScript like you're describing?

Comment: If you use Visual Studio Code, its Project Salsa will enable it to read typing files even if you're using pure JavaScript. As long as there's a `tsconfig.json` file present in the project root and the typing file is somewhere in the project, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to install the typescript compiler with npm and just compile the example into Javascript.

<s>IDK how declaration files are supposed to help here. The only way I know they are of use is to provide a interface with types for vanilla Javascript code.</s> Hmm well still I wouldn't want to lock my project to a single IDE.

As you probably know Typescript gets compiled into Javascript to run it. In the end all typescript does is make developement errors less likely because of a typing system, as well as provide a few newer Javascript features to be compiled to old JavaScript Code.

The way Typescript is made all Javascript code is valid Typescript code. So when you have the example as Javascript you can use the plug-in like that.

Just install Typescript with the Node Package Manager, preferably globally, and compile the typescript example to Javascript with a terminal by using `tsc input.ts output.js`.

It could be that you have to either add tsc to the PATH variable of your system first or just refer to the tsc (typescript compiler) executable.

Btw, you can see the compiled Javascript code in the www folder in the code of the plug-in. And honestly, typescript is no magic, if you just ignore the types (usually denoted with a `:`) it's valid Javascript code too, though it might use some features from ES6, ES7 (newer Javascript versions) etc.